# How can I pass one more parameter to the method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

update

How can I transfer the counterparty in the method so that in addition to the year and month, he will be transferred?

```
  scope :extract_by_date, -> (props) {
    if props[:months].present?
      extract_by(:year, props[:years]).extract_by(:month, props[:months])
    else
      extract_by(:year, props[:years])
    end
  }
```

I guess I need to add something like this, but it does not work, help please.

```
extract_by(:year, props[:years]).extract_by(:month, props[:months]).extract_by(:counterparty, props[:counterparty]))
```

filters.js (React/Redux)

```
render() {
  const { filter, current, handleFilterChange } = this.props;
  const monthsNames = moment.monthsShort();
  const options = {
    years: filter.years.map((year) => {
      return { value: year, label: year };
    }),
    months: monthsNames.map((monthName, index) => {
      return { value: index + 1, label: monthName };
   })
}
```

and 
conroller.rb

```
  def index
    props = {
      years: params[:year],
      months: params[:month]
    }

    unless props_valid?(props)
      return render_api({ years: registers.years }, :ok)
    end

    items = registers.extract_by_date(props).by_page(params[:page]).order(created_at: :desc) 
    render_api({ items: items, years: registers.years, counterparty: counterparty },
                 :ok, each_serializer: RegistersSerializer)
  end
```

I need to change the controller and the model so that they transfer the data to the react file.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking. Can you break down the code into the relevant parts and try not to use domain specific language.

Comment: I tried to fix it more clearly, sorry.